# How to produce a new line in the comment box?

Tags: support, comments

A simple question: How to produce a new line in the comment box?

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to put display material in comments? You can't force a newline: comments are meant to be short text statements.

Comment: Ah, I'm trying to put a preformatted block in my comment. Aside from that, I'm sorry for my act of putting such text in the description. An error dialog box displayed that my question does not pass quality standards, when my question is just simple as you have indicated. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 8):

You can't and this is considered [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

[Comments only support a limited set of markdown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

If you require more structured formatting in your formulation, then you should consider posting an answer (if that is in fact worthy of an answer). Otherwise, [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) are considered just that; off-the-cuff requests for clarification, some brief code snippets, etc.

Reference(s):

- [Line breaks not working in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165268/168244)
- [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/168244)
- [Stack Overflow comments don't have formatting tags or line breaks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50444/168244)